# Sorting numerically if the number is not at the start of a line

Tags: linux, bash, sorting, grep

I used `grep -Eo '[0-9]{1,}kg' *.dat` which filters the ones with `*kg`. Now I'm trying to sort them in increasing order. My output from grep is:

```
blue_whale.dat:240kg 
crocodile.dat:5kg 
elephant.dat:6kg
giraffe.dat:15kg
hippopotamus.dat:4kg
humpback_whale.dat:5kg
ostrich.dat:1kg
sea_turtle.dat:10kg
```

I've tried to used `sort -n`. But the sorting doesn't work.

edit:
I have bunch of files with how much each animals weight and their length. I filtered the weights of each animal. This part was easy. And then I want to order them in increasing order which I thought was just `sort -n`.

edit:
In my directory, I have many dat files.
And they contain values like 110000kg 24m 
And I need to order them in weight increasing order

Comment: show a few lines of your .dat file and the output.  Also what OS are you doing this on.

Comment: What is you expected output? Please update your question.

Comment: @kenlukas I edited the question, can you please help...spending so much time on this thing

Comment: @Ashutosh I edited the ques

Comment: @lolads Please add the content of your file.

Comment: @Ashutosh I just edited, any help would be massively appreciated

Comment: @lolads Can you paste the exact output of the `*.dat` files. Because I'm able to reproduce the output you need in increasing order using `sort -n`

Comment: The title was misleading -- the problem has nothing at all to do with `grep`, and everything to do with the number not being at the start of the line. (Unless you're referring to the filenames being added by grep, but it doesn't matter to sort *what* added them, just that they're there / that the numbers aren't first).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the command in this manner:

`grep -Eo '[0-9]{1,}kg' *.dat | sort -t: -n -k2`

Use the "-t" option to specify the colon as field separator.

You can use `-r` option for decreasing or reverse order.